# Apply a transformation to an image pyglet

Tags: python, transformation, pyglet

I am trying to make an rpg from first person perspective. I have looked at the pyglet api reference but the only thing I could find that was on the same track was the "get_transform" method and this only gave the option of flipping and rotating (as far as I could see)

Is there any way to do this in pyglet? Would I need to use some OpenGL stuff in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyglet uses OpengL, take a look at: http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've had a look through the opengl section in the programming guide and managed to get shapes on the screen and there vertices modified. But I still have the problem of how to change them based on view. I've read into heaps of stuff on the camera class but I'm unsure how it works :/

Comment: You are making a 3d perspective game, like the old doom style of camera, only 3d rendering?

Comment: Yes like doom or wolfenstein. I'm using 2d sprites

Comment: Like this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yASop1CxXfE except I'm hoping to make an rpg instead of a shooter